# Resigning: Can I recommend a coworker replace me in my resignation letter?

Tags: south-africa

I am potentially resigning from my position tomorrow to work for a company closer to home. Recently, a coworker of mine, who I won't really say I'm friends with, but am on good terms with, who completed the same developer internship that I did to become permanent, but for some reason, got placed in a different department, has been telling me that she wishes to do developer work again.

I initially told her in a hand-waving way that she must 'speak to the line manager about it', but now that I've got an offer from another company, and on the brink of leaving, want to make it up to her, and help her ease into my position during notice to take my place when I'm gone. She is always given fringe tasks to do in the advertising department, and most of the advertising team agrees that her talents are being wasted.

So in my resignation letter, which is going to be addressed to my line manager and all of HR, can I mention that there is someone within the company who I will train to take my place? I'm obviously not going to mention her name in the mail, but when my manager wants a face-to-face conversation about my resignation, I want to speak about it in more detail.

Comment: Don't say you're "grooming" her

Comment: I wouldn't put that in the letter, but you can certainly bring that up in the meeting/discussion you'll have about your resignation. That's if you genuinely think she is a good replacement for you (not just "want to make it up to her" but actually think she would be good for that position). Do you think she is a good replacement? Or are you just doing her a favour? If she "for some reason" got placed in a different department then maybe there's something the company knows (lack of aptitude, etc) that you don't know.

Comment: @Jack I know that isn't the best choice of words, I'll say 'train' or 'assist'.

Comment: The actual resignation letter should be short, simple, and to the point. Especially if your manager asks for your opinion, you can mention her in conversation.

Comment: @Jack Are you referring to [succession planning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succession_planning)?

Comment: @Underverse The word "grooming" has negative connotations, commonly associated with Epstein, Woody Allen, Biden, etc.

Comment: Are you asking whether it's proper to do so, or whether it will help your coworker get the job?

Comment: @AC Whether it's proper to do so.

Answer (score 17):

Resignation letter is not a place to mention such details. Resignation letter usually should contain the fact that you are resigning, you are giving notice and your last date of employment. It shouldn't even contain reason for leaving.

The rest of the things should follow after the resigning. Usually you will be called to HR or your manager to ask about the reasons, provide counter offers (if any). If they failed to convince you to stay, or if they don't want to stay, next steps comes. Do not mention the replacement at this stage.

Next stage will be the preparation for handover and finding replacement. Which should be immediately after the second stage. At this stage, you can mention your suggestion for replacement and why do you think so. Its entirely up to them if they accept or not.

In short, do NOT write or mention in your resignation letter, your replacement.

Comment: Everything you wrote, except when to mention a replacement is correct. Given the amount of time it takes to on-board a new employee, I'd suggest getting the potential replacement's resume in the hands of the appropriate person as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes. But it has no place in resignation letter.